# How to track which entities are updated in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on an eCommerce based web application with MVC and Entity Framework.
I just want to track/know which entities are updated. For example, when the user  changes the stock and price for any product and clicks the `Save` button, I want to track that these two entities are updated with their `ProductId`.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want to log these updates?

Comment: Yes, we can say it

Comment: Then please look at some of the many examples of Entity Framework + auditing.

Comment: Take a look at [Audit.EntityFramework](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/tree/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework#auditentityframework) library.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

This project allows to audit / track everything what's is modified. There is a lot of options available if you only want to access modified entities.

```
// using Z.EntityFramework.Plus; // Don't forget to include this.

var ctx = new EntityContext();
// ... ctx changes ...

var audit = new Audit();
audit.CreatedBy = "ZZZ Projects"; // Optional
ctx.SaveChanges(audit);

// Access to all auditing information
var entries = audit.Entries;
foreach(var entry in entries)
{
    foreach(var property in entry.Properties)
    {
    }
}
```

Documentation: [EF+ Audit](http://entityframework-plus.net/audit)

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6/

Comment: Can you please suggest where do I get this reference:  Z.EntityFramework.Plus. We have found only these: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/Downloads

Comment: @Ankita, I'm not sure to understand your question. You need first to download the right version from NuGet (The link you found is good) depending on the EF you are using and if you want all features or only one. Then you can start using the library. The "Z.EntityFramework.Plus" is only the namespace where all class can be found.

Comment: But I am unable to find any NuGet package for Z.EntityFramework.Plus. I found packages mentioned in that link. So where can I find this NuGet package

Comment: I have added the direct NuGet link for EF6

Comment: @JonathanMagnan your project is the only thing I could get working in EF Core for filters so plus 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use rowversion if it is not in the same http request.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can with this

```
//let 'myObj' is entity instance
//let db is your context instance
if ( db.Entry(myObj).State == System.Data.EntityState.Modified )
{
 //Try your code here
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is myObj? For example I have Student model so in that case I need to configure object of this model class?

Comment: As I am using EF 6 I need to write System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified

Comment: In your case your product is myObj